# I found a script that counts the days until Monday, but I don't know how to convert result to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, integer, timedelta

Here is the script:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = now = datetime.today()
today = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day)
print (timedelta(days=7-now.weekday()) + today - now)
```

I need the result to be an int because the program requires the date in int.

Comment: you mean you need the whole date in int? or just the days that you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).
You can get the days of a timedelta with the `days` property:

```py
delta = timedelta(days=7-now.weekday()) + today - now)
print(delta.days)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean int as for number of days - use timedelta.days, if you mean seconds - here's a solution for both.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = now = datetime.today()

today = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day)

td = timedelta(days=7-now.weekday()) + today - now

print(td.days)

td_seconds = td.total_seconds() 

print(round(td_seconds)) # rounded
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit confused on the goal of the script, but I assume you want to find the number of days between the current day and the following Monday.

Assumptions:

- The number of days is calculated until 12am Monday morning. In other words, the days count does not include Monday.

---

Code to count only the number of full days until Monday:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today = datetime.today()
print(int(6 - today.weekday()))
```

Output (current day is Wednesday 1:29AM):
`4`

---

Code to calculate the number of days including partial days (i.e. current day 1:29 on Wednesday, there is about 4.91 days until 12am on Monday).

Detailed view:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Get current date
today = datetime.today()

# Calculate number of days until Monday (partial days count as full day)
days_until_monday = timedelta(days=int(6 - today.weekday()) + 1)

# Get date of next Monday
next_monday = today + days_until_monday

# Format dates
today = datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, today.hour, today.minute, today.second)
next_monday = datetime(next_monday.year, next_monday.month, next_monday.day, 0, 0, 0)

# Difference up to the nearest second
delta = next_monday - today
delta = delta.total_seconds()

# Convert to days
delta = delta / 86400

# Print result
print(float(delta))
```

Output:
`4.912685185185185`

Hope this helps :)